# TIBCO EMS max connection error - too many open connections : url that returned this exception

Tags: .net, tibco, tibco-ems

I am using the shared EMS server in the organization. For my application max EMS connection configured are 512.

This has been working fine for more than two years. Recently since last 1 month, very frequently getting error -

TIBCO.EMS.ResourceAllocationException: Failed to connect to any server at

"too many open connections : url that returned this exception tcp://ems.server.url"

I check the internal EMS dashboard to trackdown the number of open connections for this server from different host.

Connections - 62

Topics - 63

Queues - 84

Sessions - 66

Producers - 180

Consumers 188

As you can see above, there are only 62 connections open, but still I am failing to create new connection saying max connection limit has been reached.

Comment: Check if connections are opened during processing and closed properly? I recommend to use spring jms wrapper for JMS broker interactions. Try printing the ems clientid while processing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration files  if you have a topic to multiple queue bridge configured. Find out which queue or topic is generating such problem:

"test.scott.3" is bridged from AIM.DEV.CORE.EVENT.TOPIC.V1 had 4101 Pending Messages of size 25.0 MB

You have to increased the maxbytes to higher value and hence the error is gone.